# How to configure Hadoop MapReduce mapper output compression if I use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce (new) API?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, compression, mapper

Is it possible to turn on mapper output compression on new `mapreduce` API and if so could you please point how? I see lot of examples doing so based on `hadoop.mapred.JobConf` API but no one for `mapreduce` API.

If it is not configurable through `new` API can I do something to get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following codes to enable the map output compression:

```
public static void enableMapOutputCompress(Job job) {
    job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("mapred.compress.map.output", true);
    job.getConfiguration().setClass("mapred.map.output.compression.codec",
            SnappyCodec.class, CompressionCodec.class);
}
```

You can change `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec` to other compression class, for example: `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec`, `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec`.

I suggest to use SnappyCodec.

Comment: Additional thanks for point to snappy codec. Happened to be really effective on reducer output. Mapper output compression barely passed 'if it worth it' checks.